# Android / Java: Canvas.drawText() set text height in px

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am looking for a way to set the text height of a Canvas.drawPaint() in px. The width of the drawn text then should increase/decrease in size to, but I only want to set the height.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(??100px??);  //What to do instead?
canvas.drawText("abc", getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, paint);
```

Thank you for hopefully coming answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the dimens.xml

In code do

```
 paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

and in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="text_size">10sp</dimen>
```

Comment: And what is a "sp" exactly?

Comment: Its scale independent pixels simillar to dp. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html